# How to remove all occurrences of string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, stringify

I am using `JSON.stringify` to convert object into string as follows:

```
JSON.stringify(obj).replace(/[{}]/g, '').slice(1, -1)
```

I am getting below output:

```
"null,null,"Heading":"Heading1""
```

I want to remove all occurrences of null from the above string, for which I am using `replace`

```
JSON.stringify(obj).replace(/[{}]/g, '').slice(1, -1).replace('null,', '')
```

But it only removes the first occurrence of `null` string

```
 "null,"Heading":"Heading1""
```

Desired output:

```
"Heading":"Heading1""
```

Comment: Why replace it in the string and not the object/array you're stringifying?

Comment: Don't ever tamper with JSON.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace all occurrences of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As peeps said in comments **may be the best way for this is to get rid of `null` element in the first place**, so if you want to do that you should iterate through your object then check for `null` items.

For this cause this may come handy:

```js
Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => (obj[key] == null) && delete obj[key]);
```

Otherwise, **you should consider using a global flag (`/g`)** in your regex, in order to remove all `null` occurrence.

You can achieve this with something like this:

```js
.replace(/null,/g, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

The .replace() method only replaces the first occurrence. Perform global replacement as

```
.replace(/null,/g, '')
```

Hope it helps!